# Including fax contact information

Tags: forms

For an **attorney's** website **contact** information,

- include a **fax number**?
- Is this superfluous information? Can it be taken away?
- I've had **many** unfortunate experiences with my college website. They list both the fax and the telephone number. I call the fax number on my phone and it makes a harsh screeching noise in my ear. It's the worst thing in the world.

Comment: Do their clients need to fax information to them? We can't know that.

Comment: I gave it a downvote as it's not a question for us to answer. This is a question for the client to answer.

Comment: I edited it to provide more context for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attorney actively uses/receives faxes, then I would say yes, you should generally include it, unless your client specifies the contact information that he/she would like to make available to the public.

- If the attorney may receive faxes from non-clients or prospective clients, then this information would need to be included on the website to allow for this.
- If clients or other contacts will fax important forms, papers, etc. to the attorney, they might have lost a business card or a scrap of paper with the contact information and would expect to be able to find it on the website.  Leaving out this information would not satisfy the user's needs and causes more difficulty for them to find the fax number.

However, your client may decide to leave out the fax number if they do not want the general public to be able to fax them.  Some websites will only provide a contact form to reduce spam and protect their information.